# Visual C# Add Item to contextMenuStrip with link

Tags: c#

How can I add an item to a contextmenustrip, as well as code the button_click action for it?

I'm making a web browser application, and I have a drop down menu of 'favorite' websites.  When someone clicks a button, it adds the title of the website into the dropdown menu, but I also need it navigable to the website URL that was inputted. I have no idea how to add button click actions when I add a new item to a contextmenustrip.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a WinForms application?

If so, in the Visual Studio designer, after you drag a contextMenuStrip from the boolbox, it allows you to type new entries at the contextMenuStrip (click where it says 'Type Here' to add a new item).  If you are going back to an existing contextMenuStrip, you will have to make it appear by clicking on the contextMenuStrip item at the bottom of the designer.

Once you have the item, you can just double-click on it to whatever code you want to execute on the click event.  (This is the default event; for other events you will have to double-click the appropriate event from the Properties pane.